# Creating a Custom Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

we want to rejuvenate a legacy DB application by using EF 6 (plus some other components).
There are certain security and multi-tenancy features that would have to be placed into EF, because they are not supported by EF so far. We checked out that our necessary changes can be put to work within EF.

However, is it even *possible* to get it running on a server? Or would it necessarily collide with other OS components which, maybe, assume the *original* EF, for instance by somehow calling back using the strong name of the original assemblies? Did anyone ever get this running?

(Or maybe I should ask this question on Codeplex' general questions?)

--Happy new year 2014 to everybody!

@DarkWalker, thank you for answering. - DLLs were already built and are working in Release configuration in Visual Studio. In order to get the custom EF running on a server in a production environment, we have to switch off the assembly signing / or verification (bad idea), or sign it ourselves. To this end, the strong name of the assemblies has to be changed, something I have never done before.

When trying to do so, I saw an error message that referenced the mscorlib, which is what got me second-guessing the whole approach. I just want to make sure that, after much work, I do not end up in a blind alley.

To answer my question, it would be enough if someone would raise his/her hand and say: Yes we have a custom EF running in a production environment with/without our own assembly signing.

Thank you very much!
YaEFn

Answer (score 1):

EF is [open source](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/). You can modify sources however you like, compile it and put dlls into your application's folder - it will not affect other applications on the same machine.